# Django 1.6 PostgreSQL: __contains filter versus pgtrgm with indexing

Tags: django, postgresql

Using Django 1.6 ....I have read the filter __contains for Postgres uses LIKE on postgres. Does Django ORM creates a index for faster searching when it uses __contains? And if so, does it create a GiST or GIN index?

Or would it be better perfomance wise for me to use pg_trgm, index the columns to be searched manually with GIN, and run the manual queries?

Answer (score 0):

Django won't create any index other then (explicetly defined) B-tree index.